# Rectangular node with cross (plus) marks at the edges

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I want to divide the working area into some parts and then mark their borders with plus marks. I can do this separately:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}


\tikzset{quarterpage/.style={draw,text width=.47*\textwidth, minimum height=.5*\textheight, 
    minimum width=.5*\textwidth, text depth=.47*\textheight,  
    label={[yshift=8mm]below:\rule{.35\textwidth}{.7pt}}}   }
    
 
\newcommand{\posA}{($.5*(current page text area.north west)+.5*(current page text area)$)}
\newcommand{\posB}{($.5*(current page text area.north east)+.5*(current page text area)$)}
\newcommand{\posC}{($.5*(current page text area.south west)+.5*(current page text area)$)}
\newcommand{\posD}{($.5*(current page text area.south east)+.5*(current page text area)$)}
    

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[quarterpage]at\posA{Some text};  
\node[quarterpage]at\posB{Another card};
\node[quarterpage]at\posC{Something else};
\node[quarterpage]at\posD{And what in fact?};
\end{tikzpicture}

\newpage

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[name=s,shape=rectangle] {Rectangle\vrule width 1pt height 2cm};
  \foreach \anchor in
    {north west, north east,
     south west, south east}
     \draw[shift=(s.\anchor)] plot[mark=+,mark options = {scale= 5}] coordinates{(0,0)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but any try to replace the lines like in the first picture with plus marks as in the second picture fails. How should I mix the two definitions?

[image]

[image]

To be more precise: In the second version, the edges are labeled by the characteristic points of the node. Can I set it somewhere in `quarterpage/.style`?

Comment: Fails in what way?

Comment: @cfr I want to use my \node[quarterpage]at\posA{Some text}; and so on, but they should have no lines, only marks at the edges. However, naive attempts to mix the two solutions give only syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see the purpose for this strange thing and way of doing it, but it can be done

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
quarterpage/.style={
text width=.47*\textwidth, minimum height=.5*\textheight+20pt, 
minimum width=.5*\textwidth+20pt, text depth=.47*\textheight,  
label={[yshift=8mm]below:\rule{.35\textwidth}{.7pt}},
inner sep=10pt, outer sep=0pt,
path picture={\path plot[mark=+, mark options={scale=5}] coordinates{
 ([above right=10pt]path picture bounding box.south west)
 ([above left =10pt]path picture bounding box.south east)
 ([below right=10pt]path picture bounding box.north west)
 ([below left =10pt]path picture bounding box.north east)
};}}}
\newcommand{\posA}{($.5*(current page text area.north west)+.5*(current page text area)$)}
\newcommand{\posB}{($.5*(current page text area.north east)+.5*(current page text area)$)}
\newcommand{\posC}{($.5*(current page text area.south west)+.5*(current page text area)$)}
\newcommand{\posD}{($.5*(current page text area.south east)+.5*(current page text area)$)}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[quarterpage]at\posA{Some text};  
\node[quarterpage]at\posB{Another card};
\node[quarterpage]at\posC{Something else};
\node[quarterpage]at\posD{And what in fact?};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Full page split in quarters with text and crosses]

Comment: Thank you! +1. The path picture trick is new for me.

Comment: Yes `path picture` is very useful. Unfortunately it can only draw thing inside a node. -that is way I enlarge the nodes by `10pt` above - to make room for the full cross.

Comment: It was strange for me that we could define a style, and add marks in a defined node, but if the node is only potential in a TikZ style, adding marks is impossible. Hence the trick with the path saves at least part of the possibilities, although clipping to the note is unpleasant, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

It's not at all clear in what respect you consider the result 'fails'. Certainly it compiles fine.

Taking a wild guess, are you looking for

[[image: wild guess as to target image1]

If so, you just need `inner sep=0pt, line width=0pt`.

Comment: No, no. I want to use my `\node[quarterpage]at\posA{Some text};` and so on, but they should have no lines, only marks at the edges.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke The line is part of the `some text` in your example. It isn't a line created by the drawing of the node. It's just the `\vrule ...` you've got in the node's content.

Comment: I know this. This is only a filling. I want to replace full oblongs with marks at their edges, with the same text inside.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Which was my point. But use hpekristiansen's answer. This was just a quick and dirty minimal fix. It does what you asked, but I suspect you didn't want the padding removed.